# Is the following claim true in $=\mathbb{R}^{d} \times L^{2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

In my thesis I'm studying an article with which I'm having the following problem: let $E=\mathbb{R}^{d} \times L^{2}([0,+\infty))$ be the Hilbert space with norm
$
\|\alpha\|^{2}:=|x|^{2}+\|z\|_{L^{2}}^{2} 
$
$\forall \alpha=(x, z) \in E$ and the corresponding inner product $\langle., .\rangle .$ Let $T$ be the linear unbounded operator on $E$ with domain $D(T)=\mathbb{R}^{d} \times H^{1}$ and defined by
$$
T(y, w)=(y-w(0),-\dot{w}), \forall(y, w) \in D(T)
$$

The unbounded operator $I+T^{*} T$ has domain
$$
D\left(I+T^{*} T\right)=\left\{(y, w) \in E: w \in H^{2}, y=w(0)-\dot{w}(0)\right\}
$$
and is given by
$$
\left(I+T^{*} T\right)(y, w):=(2 y-w(0),-\ddot{w}+w), \forall(y, w) \in D\left(T^{*} T\right)
$$
Now define $B=\left(I+T^{*} T\right)^{-1}$.
For $\alpha=(x, z) \in E,(y, w)=B(\alpha)$ is defined as follows: firstly, $w \in H^{2}$ is the solution of
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\ddot{w}+w &=& z & \text { in }(0,+\infty) \\
-2 \dot{w}(0)+w(0) &=& x
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
secondly, $y$ is defined by
$$
y=\frac{x+w(0)}{2}=w(0)-\dot{w}(0)
$$
Set $B=\left(B_{1}, B_{2}\right)$ where $B_{2}(x, z)=w$ and $B_{1}(x, z)=y$. Setting:
$$
\|\alpha\|_{B}^{2}:=\langle B(\alpha), \alpha\rangle, \forall \alpha=(x, z) \in E
$$
Using the definition of $w,y$ we arrive at:
$$
\|\alpha\|_{B}^{2}=\frac{|x|^{2}}{2}+\frac{|w(0)|^{2}}{2}+\|w\|_{H^{1}}^{2}
$$
This is the setting in [Carlier, Guillaume, and Rabah Tahraoui. "Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equations for the optimal control of a state equation with memory."], p. 758.

Now he claims that
\begin{equation}
\|z\|_{\left(H^{1}\right)^{\prime}}^{2}=\|w+\varphi\|_{H^{1}}^{2}
\end{equation}
where
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\ddot{\varphi}+\varphi &=0 \\
\dot{\varphi}(0) &=\frac{x-w(0)}{2},
\end{aligned} \quad \text { in }(0,+\infty)\right.
$$
so that he can have the following bounds for $m,C \geq 0$ :
$$
\|z\|_{\left(H^{1}\right)^{\prime}}^{2} \leq 2\left(\|w\|_{H^{1}}^{2}+\|\varphi\|_{H^{1}}^{2}\right) \leq 2\|w\|_{H^{1}}^{2}+m\left(|x|^{2}+|w(0)|^{2}\right)
$$
$$
\|(x, z)\|_{B}^{2} \geq C\left(|x|^{2}+\|z\|_{\left(H^{1}\right)^{\prime}}^{2}\right), \forall(x, z) \in E
$$
My question is: why is \begin{equation}
\|z\|_{\left(H^{1}\right)^{\prime}}^{2}=\|w+\varphi\|_{H^{1}}^{2}
\end{equation}
true?

The quetion is related to [Why is this the adjoint operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265799/why-is-this-the-adjoint-operator)
where you can find the contruction of the adjoint.

Comment: Didn't have enough time to read this, but let me see if I can be of assistance in some distant future.

Comment: ok thanks, let me know in case